# How to access to updated variable in multi processing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I write a code with 2 process, but when I print the t variable in f function I get the initial value.

How can I update the t variable in f function?

**UPDATE**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import random

t = []


def f():
    global t
    while True:
        print("f", t)
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    while True:
        t.append(random.randint(0,10))
        print("main", t)
        time.sleep(10)

#main [5]
#f []
#main [5, 9]
#f []
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your `x` variable a ctypes object, instead of a plain integer type:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Value
manager = Manager()
x = manager.Value('i', 10)
```

Then use the `x.value` attribute to share it amongst different processes:

```
x.value += 10
print(x.value)
```

Comment: manager = Manager()
I get RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import random

t = []


def f():
    global t
    while True:
        print("f", t)
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    while True:
        t.append(random.randint(0,10))
        print("main", t[len(t)-1]) # this prints the last value appended to t
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: +10 Its just example, I want to be able change global variable

Comment: All you need do is allow function f take a parameter which will be the increment value. Then pass an argument into function f when calling the Process. I've updated my answer to show this. (i pass 20 as the argument, you can use some other values if you wish)

Comment: @ronkolel does this answer your question?

Comment: I've updated my answer to print the last value generated for t. But, use should know that with `t.append(random.randint(0,10))` you keep and newly generated index to a list. This list can grow very large and difficult to manage, considering that you are using an unbounded `while` loop.